# Remove commas using php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, browser

i have a column name fighters which include some value in mysql such as,

| fighters       |

| Rock       |

| John Cena, |

| UnderTaker,|

So, I want when i Display it in a browser it should appear like

Rock

John Cena

UnderTaker

I just want to remove commas from database using PHP

Any Help will be appreciated..

Comment: do you have instances that a comma exists between words? example `John, Cena,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give

```
str_replace(",","",$str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use REPLACE() in the SQL query

```
SELECT REPLACE(fighters, ',', '') FROM  table
```

Though why you'd want to do this in query rather than stripping it on the php side if beyond me

Comment: It doesn't specify anywhere that it has to be done with MySQL

Comment: ...but there is the `mysql` tag on the question, so it is certainly appropriate.