# How to remove commas of integer from MY SQL select query

Tags: mysql

I am using a mySQL statement that returns me average of values as comma separated integer.

Eg : 2,109. But I want my output to be plain integer like 2109. Please help me on this.

Comment: How did you get commas into your numbers? MySQL query results will not do that with integers unless you use the [FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function. Are you storing numbers in a string column?

Comment: Maybe the query return an average of integers, as a double...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove commas using php from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231080/remove-commas-using-php-from-mysql)

Answer (score 16):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(fieldname, ',', '')
FROM ...
```

Or if type of *fieldname* is integer use this query

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(fieldname), ',', '')
FROM ...
```