# Remove special char using select statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I am using the following query to update (remove) the existing sql char

```
UPDATE tblCompany
SET CompanyName = replace(CompanyName , '''', '')
```

is there anyway when I try to strip those spl char when I use select statment ?

like

```
Select ID,CompanyName(replace(CompanyName , '''', '')) from tblcompany
```

Comment: Select ID,replace(CompanyName , '''', '') as CompanyName from tblcompany

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have replace with like this.

```
 SELECT ID, REPLACE(CompanyName ,'''', "") as company_name FROM tblCompany
```

[For detailed example click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336666/how-to-remove-commas-of-integer-from-my-sql-select-query)

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not even valid SQL Syntax. Did this really work for you @User? And why link to a MySQL example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below query:

```
select ID,replace(CompanyName , '''', '') as CompanyName from tblCompany;
```

But Remember this is just **temporary** ,holds only till current selection. It will not be updated in the main table.