# Removing commas in varchar to get number and test

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a serious problem with varchar in mysql.
This is my query :

```
SELECT ak.`address`, ak.lien1_amount, ak.`comp`, ak.`zestimate`, ak.`counvalue`, IFNULL(COALESCE(ak.comp, ak.zestimate, ak.counvalue), 0) AS cmazestcv, CEIL( CAST(ak.lien1_amount AS DECIMAL(10,5)) ) AS testnum 
FROM allinformationk AS ak 
LEFT JOIN `home_buyers_alias1` ON ak.`house id` = `home_buyers_alias1`.`house id` 
WHERE ak.`is_deleted` = 'no' AND ( (CASE WHEN ak.`sale date 4` IS NOT NULL THEN ak.`sale date 4` WHEN ak.`sale date 3` IS NOT NULL THEN ak.`sale date 3` WHEN ak.`sale date 2` IS NOT NULL THEN ak.`sale date 2` ELSE ak.`sale date` END) IS NOT NULL) 
    AND ( CAST(IFNULL(COALESCE(ak.comp, ak.zestimate, ak.counvalue), 0) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) > CAST(ak.lien1_amount AS DECIMAL(10,5)) ) 
    AND ak.lien1_amount IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

This is the result of my query : [image]

The fields lien1_amount, comp, zestimate, counvalue are VARCHAR. This is why I am casting them to DECIMAL in my query. But still can't get it for testing as integer, you can see what lien1_amount gives in testnum column when I want to transform it to decimal.
How to change those varchar with comas to amount of money and test them ?
I can not do it since two days now.

Comment: How all the values of lien1_amount are stored i.e. 1234,34 etc and you want them as 1234.34 ?

Comment: Did you try using `REPLACE(ak.lien1_amount, ',', '')`?

Comment: Abhik, they are stored just as string. And the database is huge now.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, let me test and see.

Comment: `select cast( replace('123,34',',','.') as DECIMAL(8,2)) ;` thats how it needs to be.

Comment: It is weird now, let me update the image result and the new query

Comment: It seems replace removed the value of field lien1_amount from results ...

Comment: replace the values ?? `replace('123,34',',','.')` will make `123,34` to `123.34` and then cast is applied on it.

Comment: It is working Abhik, but I just removed the ',' by '' not '.'. So dasblinkenlight was right. Some data were empty and not null that is why I thought it was removing the value, as the result was changing! Thanks guys, please post the answer!

Comment: Garbage in. Garbage out. I'm afraid :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove commas using php from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231080/remove-commas-using-php-from-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the said columns are of type `varchar` and hold *numeric* value always, then just `replace` the *comma* and use the result. No explicit cast is required.

And, if columns `comp`, `zestimate`, `counvalue` too contain *comma* as part of them, then apply `replace` on them too.

```
SELECT ak.`address`
     , CEIL( replace( ifnull( ak.lien1_amount, 0 ), ',', '' ) ) as lien1_amount
     , replace( ifnull( ak.`comp`, 0 ), ',', '' ) as `comp`
     , replace( ifnull( ak.`zestimate`, 0 ), ',', '' ) as `zestimate`
     , replace( ifnull( ak.`counvalue`, 0 ), ',', '' ) as `counvalue`
     , replace( ifnull( COALESCE( ak.comp, ak.zestimate, ak.counvalue )
               , 0 ), ',', '' ) AS cmazestcv
  FROM allinformationk AS ak 
  LEFT JOIN `home_buyers_alias1` 
         ON ak.`house id` = `home_buyers_alias1`.`house id` 
 WHERE ak.`is_deleted` = 'no' 
   AND ak.lien1_amount IS NOT NULL 
   AND COALESCE(   ak.`sale date 4`
                 , ak.`sale date 3`
                 , ak.`sale date 2`
                 , ak.`sale date`   ) IS NOT NULL 
   AND replace( 
         IFNULL( COALESCE( ak.comp, ak.zestimate, ak.counvalue ), 0 ), ',', '' ) 
       > replace( ak.lien1_amount, ',', '' )  
 LIMIT 0, 10;
```